# Regex to exclude domain paths starting with /(es|fr|it)/?

Tags: regex, url, regex-negation

Trying to come up with a Regex that matches a uri path that doesn't start with a country prefix.  Following use cases are an example:

```
'^/$'          == true
'^/es$'        == false
'^/es/$'       == false
'^/es/.*$'     == false
'^/escro.*$'   == true
'^/lies$'      == true # newish
'^/lies/$'     == true # newish
'^/fr$'        == false
'^/fr/$'       == false
'^/fr/.*$'     == false
'^/freedom/$'  == true
'^/it$'        == false
'^/it/$'       == false
'^/it/.*$'     == false
'^/item/.*$'   == true
'^/foo/bar/$'  == true
```

Summary: Should match any URL that doesn't pass "^/(fr|it|es)$" or "^/(fr|it|es)/.*$"

Comment: Why would you not just use the boolean opposite of the match result? What is the application, anyway?

Comment: It's a 3rd party system (Ensighten) that only allows "include" at the moment (*disclaimer: as far as I know*)

Comment: @Tom - I've updated my answer with a much more efficient version. Can you find any test cases that it does not work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a much more compact version that worked for me:

```
^/[^/]*(?<!/(?:es|fr|it))(?:/.*?)?$
```

I used a PHP bootstrap to test it, and [you can see from the demo](http://viper-7.com/0u7HgF) that it passes all of the test cases.

**Regex:**

```
^               - Start of string
/               - Match a forward slash
[^/]*           - Match anything that's not a forward slash, 0 or more times
(?<!            - Negative lookbehind making sure
  /(?:es|fr|it) -      We didn't match a forward slash followed by (es|fr|it)
)   
(?:/.*?)?       - Match a forward slash followed by any number of characters, optionally
$               - End of string
```

Comment: Was thinking through the Negative lookbehind and realized we still exclude urls like ^/.*(es|fr|it)/ which would fail on pages like ^/workit$: http://viper-7.com/J5c7XT

Comment: @Tom - Fixed. Try it now. Also, in m opinion, you should've opened a new question instead of unaccepting an answer - My original post completely answered your original question, and you changed the requirements, which warrants another question in itself.

Comment: Apologies; didn't think through the the implications. Thank you sincerely for all your help (Regex and SO)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using negative lookbehind?